Telerik DataAccess eager loading not working
I am using the sample database SofiaCarRental from Telerik.
I am trying to fetch all categories from the database and in the same query include the cars and rental rates.
I am aware this product is deprecated, however, we still need to maintain our application that is using this product.
Here's my program
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new FluentModel();

        var query = context.Categories;

        var fetchStrategy = new FetchStrategy();

        fetchStrategy.LoadWith<Category>(category => category.Cars);

        fetchStrategy.LoadWith<Category>(category => category.RentalRates); // <- This is not joined (look at the output SQL below)

        query = query.LoadWith(fetchStrategy);

        var queryString = query.ToString();
    }
}

Here's the value of the queryString
SELECT a.[CategoryID] AS COL1
    ,a.[CategoryID] AS COL2
    ,a.[CategoryName] AS COL3
    ,a.[ImageFileName] AS COL4
    ,b.[CarID] AS COL5
    ,b.[ABS] AS COL6
    ,b.[ASR] AS COL7
    ,b.[AirConditioner] AS COL8
    ,b.[Available] AS COL9
    ,b.[CarYear] AS COL10
    ,b.[CategoryID] AS COL11
    ,b.[CategoryID] AS COL12
    ,b.[DVDPlayer] AS COL13
    ,b.[ImageFileName] AS COL14
    ,b.[Latitude] AS COL15
    ,b.[Longitude] AS COL16
    ,b.[Make] AS COL17
    ,b.[Model] AS COL18
    ,b.[Mp3Player] AS COL19
    ,b.[Navigation] AS COL20
    ,b.[NumberOfRatings] AS COL21
    ,b.[Rating] AS COL22
    ,b.[TagNumber] AS COL23
FROM [Categories] a
LEFT JOIN [Cars] AS b ON (a.[CategoryID] = b.[CategoryID])
ORDER BY COL1
    ,COL11

I am expecting the output SQL to have a LEFT JOIN [RentalRates]
Is this confirmed as a bug?
Is this simply not possible?
Am I doing something wrong here?
